# Avalanche effect of a Zener diode, or simulator bug?

Tags: simulation, zener, random, falstad

[image: screenshot of the circuit]

On the Falstad simulator, I tried to illustrate the phenomenon of the avalanche effect of Zener diodes. I've added a capacitor to remove the DC component, too.

However, I'm not sure that the (very low) current obtained is what I would expect. How can I be sure that this is not just a floating point approximation error? Also, is my circuit correct to produce a random signal thanks to the avalanche effect of the Zener diodes?

[Here is a link to the simulation.](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKADdxiURNuwvwKPFBEAWKmhFUYCFgCdOfISGyFhYZVTDxILAF4q1PDN1Xrl3ACZ0AZgEMArgBsALgz10AdnTksAxobmwggagsISPNCEhKII2AgoCMTakNgYCBiMYEgwcKwA7orGpka8UCyFZsUUoWW6APbUEFooQsRQsHkd8M081NgsQA)

Comment: looks like a bug to me - you're measuring the voltage on the negative terminal with respect to ground, where ground hasnt been defined

Comment: I see. Could you suggest a simple circuit to illustrate avalanche effect?

Comment: I'm not sure that falstad includes the underlying avalanche charactersitrics in the diode model, so it may not be possible at all